# Sage Pay - The VendorTxCode you supplied is an invalid length

Tags: php, forms, opayo

I am trying to do the form integration with Sage Pay. I am getting the error:

```
VPSProtocol=2.23
Status=INVALID
StatusDetail=The VendorTxCode you supplied is an invalid length.  VendorTxCodes should be between 1 to 40 characters long.
```

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    //echo "<br/>Padding:".str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad)."<";
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
    $key = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    $iv = $key;

    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

        $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
    }
    return $enc;
}
$str = "VendorTxCode=34234234234&Currency=GBP";
$datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
$cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);
?>
<html>
<form name="pp_form" action="https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPServerGateway.asp?Service=VendorRegisterTx" method="post">
    <input name="VPSProtocol" type="hidden" value=2.23 />
    <input name="TxType" type="hidden" value=PAYMENT />
    <input name="Vendor" type="hidden" value="myusername" />
    <input name="Crypt" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $cryptpadded;?> />
    <p>Click here to submit 
        <input type="submit" value="here">
    </p>
</form>
</html>
```

Any help/suggestions much appreciated

Alex

Comment: I got it to work by creating a new input field named VendorTxCode but I'm not sure if you are allowed to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not do it that way if it is working then it should not be a problem.

However the error may not be your VendorTxCode as the SagePay error reporting does sometimes respond with an unrelated or 'knock on' effect error code, so one error causes a different error flag to be reported. (It is quite good but all I am saying is it is not perfect.)

A simple way to check is to encrypt, then decrypt just the vendorTxCode and see what you are getting. The official limit is 40 characters. If you have an encryption problem then it will show up.

If all is well it must be another field causing errors somewhere. Perhaps you have referred to that field again somewhere when cutting and pasting to make all the other fields. Check the contents of your text string before encryption and check the contents of the entire string for a double reference to the vendor code.

I hope that helps,

Best wishes,

Paul.